Why Anbox doesn't work on Ubuntu 24.04 with XFCE?
I tried to install it with this command: sudo apt install anbox, but I got the error that it couldn't be located, so I installed it with command: sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox, and I didn't have errors, after I installed ADB and rebooted the system(with sudo reboot, because without reboot I got an error).
But I can’t open it either through search or through adb install, adb doesn’t see it, even through adb devices.
Using terminal I have:
NAME:
    anbox - anbox

USAGE:
    anbox [command options] [arguments...]

COMMANDS:
    check-features                 Check that the host system supports all necessary features
    wait-ready                     Wait until the Android system has successfully booted
    system-info                    Print various information about the system we're running on
    launch                         Launch an Activity by sending an intent
    session-manager                Run the the anbox session manager  
    version                        Print the version of the daemon    
    help                           Print a short help message


Anbox was deprecated on February 3, 2023 as it is no longer being actively maintained.

@kyodake  Then, what about analogous things?

Use Waydroid instead (Wayland only).
Install the dependencies of the installer
sudo apt install curl ca-certificates -y

Add the official repo
curl https://repo.waydro.id | sudo bash

Install
sudo apt install waydroid -y

Enable the container service
sudo systemctl enable --now waydroid-container

Now, run the app from the menu.

Waydroid uses wayland, but I have XFCE and it doesn't support it

As of February 3, 2023, Anbox is deprecated. From the Anbox Github page:

The Anbox project was once ago created in 2017 to bring Android to any Linux based desktop operating system. It's development has however stalled in the past years and it's only fair to say that now in 2023 it's no longer actively developed.

TL;DR: The Anbox project is dead.
Furthermore, it states there are 2 other options:

If you're looking for a solution to run Android on your Linux desktop:

Waydroid is rebuilding the original idea behind Anbox with explicit focus on modern Wayland powered desktop environments.

If you're looking for a solution to run Android in the cloud:

Anbox Cloud as a solution developed by Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu, to bring Android at scale to any cloud with support for ultra low latency video streaming and recent Android versions.



Waydroid uses wayland, but I have XFCE, and it doesn’t support it
